# Some weird behavior of my angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new in this field and trying to write a website, but I meet one problem. This is a simple version of my code which can run on your laptop:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/all.js"></script>
    <script>
        var show=false
        var notshow=true
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainControl">
        Hide HTML: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar">
        <div ng-show="myVar">
            <button>Sign Up</button>
            <button>Log In</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="show">
            <button>Sign Up</button>
            <button>Log In</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="logged">
            <button>Sign Up</button>
            <button>Log In</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="notshow">
            <button>Sign Up</button>
            <button>Log In</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="visiter">
            <button>Sign Up</button>
            <button>Log In</button>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

About the myApp and all.js, I haven't write much about it. like this:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('myApp',[])
})()

(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp').controller('mainControl',function($scope){
        $scope.logged=false;
        $scope.visiter=true;
    })
})()
```

When you run it, you can find the five ng-shows don't work at all. If I delete `ng-controller="mainControl"` the first ng-show works well, but the others don't work.
I have tried for a long time and can't find any rules in this. Could you modify this code and give me the right version? or just tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: what is the requirement to use this much ng-show?

Comment: in fact, only one is needed, but I am doing some test about usage of variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works well here,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainControl', function($scope) {
  $scope.logged = false;
  $scope.visiter = true;
})
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="mainControl">
  Hide HTML:
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar">
  <div ng-show="myVar">
    <button>Sign Up</button>
    <button>Log In</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="show">
    <button>Sign Up</button>
    <button>Log In</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="logged">
    <button>Sign Up</button>
    <button>Log In</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="notshow">
    <button>Sign Up</button>
    <button>Log In</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="visiter">
    <button>Sign Up</button>
    <button>Log In</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/zfHaJmk2nZ4Q2H6xhUB8?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not proficient with javascript, so I can't comment on that

```
(function(){... code ...})())
```

pattern you are using, but you are defintely forgot `()` on the second block.